# What does the "Rva+Base" mean in a MSVC linker generated map file?

Tags: c, linker, static-linking

I compiled a C program and linked with the Microsoft linker **link.exe**.
The linker generated a *.map file. Below are some snippets:

```
 Start         Length     Name                   Class
 0001:00000000 00000180H .text                   CODE
 0001:00000180 00049158H .text$mn                CODE
 0002:00000000 000090c4H .rdata                  DATA
 0002:000090c4 00000130H .rdata$zzzdbg           DATA
 0003:00000000 00002060H .data                   DATA
 0003:00002060 00001370H .bss                    DATA
 0004:00000000 00002790H .pdata                  DATA
 0005:00000000 000003e4H .xdata                  DATA

  Address         Publics by Value       Rva+Base             Lib:Object
 0002:000000c0       _gVar               0000000000049660     MyLib:File1.obj
```

My understanding is:

The `.rdata` section has the index `0002` with the length `0x90c4`.

The `_gVar` global variable has the Address like `0002:000000c0`, so it lives in the `.rdata` seciton with the **section offset** `0xc0`.

The **base address** of the `.rdata` section is decided **by the loader at runtime**.

My confusion is about the `Rva+Base` column.

I checked the binary file at offset `0x49660`. It contains exactly the value I assigned for the `_gVar`. So it seems `Rva+Base` is **the offset from the beginning of the file**.

But I think the `Rva + Base` should equal to `absolute virtual address`, which can only be **decided by the loader at runtime**.

How could it be the file offset? Or an unfortunate typo in the column name?

(Btw, I searched a lot for an authoritative reference about the .map file generated by link.exe. But no luck so far. If anyone can share some resource, it will be deeply appreciated.)

### ADD 1 - 5:31 PM 4/8/2019

Based on `500 - Internal Server Error`'s comment, I use [CFF Explorer](https://ntcore.com/?page_id=388) to verify the PE sections. It looks like below:

[image: PE sections]

According to the [PE sepc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/debug/pe-format#section-table-section-headers):

> **Virtual Address**: For executable images, the address of the first byte of the section relative to the **image base** when the section is
>   loaded into memory.
>
> **Raw Address/PointerToRawData**: The file pointer to the first page of the section within the COFF file.

These 2 columns have the same data in my scenario.

And in the PE Optional Header, the ImageBase is **0** (this is because of my link flag `/BASE:0`):

[image: ImageBase]

When linker generated the .map file, it has no knowledge about where the image will be loaded at runtime. So it **has to** use the `ImageBase=0` to calculate the `Rva+Base` column.

The `_gVar`'s absolute virtual address = ImageBase(0) + .rdata Virtual Address(0x495A0) + offset into .rdata (0xc0) = 0x49660

In my case,

1. The `Virtual Address` column has the same value as `Raw Address` column.
2. And `ImageBase = 0` has the same effect of `file beginning offset = 0`

So the final `absolute virtual address` equals the `file offset`, **but this is only specific to my scenario**.

Comment: Parse the PE header. It has a table with the location of each section, both as an offset into the file on disk and as an offset to the module's load address in memory when the PE is loaded as an executable or dll. [Here is a link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/debug/pe-format) to the PE specification.